# NSMutableString append does nothing

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to Objective-C after using C++.
I got a problem with using NSMutableString during XML file parsing.
I have struct with NSMutableString like this:

```
struct HotelStruct {
...
NSMutableString *h_name;
...
};
```

Then, I declare CurrentStruct as instance variable of my ParserDelegate:

```
@interface ParserDelegate : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
...
struct HotelStruct CurrentStruct;
...
}
```

Finally, I am trying to append a string to CurrentStruct.h_name (m_isName == YES)  :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
if (m_isName) {
[CurrentStruct.h_name appendString:string];
}
```

But debugger says that CurrentStruct.h_name remains 0x0 after executing AppendString as before it, while string variable has the needed value.
I am kinda confused because it looks like appendString is just skipped.
I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Sending a message to nil always results in a no-op in ObjC. If you know that CurrentStruct.h_name == 0x0, appendString: or any other message you send it won't make any difference. Think of it as multiplication with 0

Comment: oh that does explain some things. looks like CurrentStruct.h_name becomes nil somewhere. I am finishing project of another guy, so i guess there may be answer in his code. Thanks a lot, i really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your string object :

```
h_name = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

and don't forget to release it when you are done :

```
[h_name release];
```

Comment: Since its burried in the structure, you'd have to do CurrentStruct.h_name = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; and the same to release

Comment: i do init it with
'CurrentStruct.h_name = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];'
But it doesn't change anything..

Comment: so can you plz post your initilization code and the relevant part of the flow ?

Comment: `-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
...
CurrentStruct.h_name = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}`

Comment: So make sure the string it first initialized before the append code is reached. The null pointer error explicitly states that the object was not initialized

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for not using a standard object instead of structure? That's probably happening because the `NSString` has not been init/allocated.

Try this:

```
CurrentStruct-> h_name = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Comment: Probably the reason is C++ usage :)
I allocated MutableString but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

     if (m_isName) {

         if(!CurrentStruct.h_name)
             CurrentStruct.h_name = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

           [CurrentStruct.h_name appendString:string];

           NSLog(CurrentStruct.h_name);
           NSLog(m_isName);
       }
    }
```

Note:Please check the console logs and **Don't forget to release the memory** after usage.

Comment: The user made no reference to ViewControllers, you shouldn't assume that they are using them. On the whole, your answer points out the problem and shows how to fix it, so I didn't downvote

Comment: This will overwrite the string every time the parser finds new characters. I think this would generate very unexpected results.